# Contract First with OpenAPI Spring Boot and Page as return object

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, openapi, openapi-generator-maven-plugin, contract-first

I'm busy with a contract first approach with openAPI and Spring Boot.
First I had a nice `RestController` with the return type `Page<Output>` where I can return the data that Spring Data has given me from the database.

Now I try to reconstruct this with a contract first approach, only when I generate the code with the openapi maven plugin it generate a Object with the attributes in it.

I have tried with importMapping `PageObject=org.springframework.data.domain.Page` but that doesn't work. Has anyone got this working?